# $\binom{n}{k}$ modulo prime power for large $n$ and small $k$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I have to compute several value of $\binom{n}{k}$ mod $p^a$ for prime $p$ over a range of $k$, where $n$ is large and fixed, and $k$ is small and dynamic.

Is there a way to speed the process up? If I use iterative identities, I often run into coprimality issues that prevent me from inverting the denominators.

I've found Granville's method (generalized Lucas) but it is too slow to compute it for each binomial.

Bounds: $n$ around $10^8$ or so. $k$ at most around $10^5$. Modulus can be a prime power up to $10^8$ (roughly).

Comment: I should add that $k$ is small, but not so small where I can store all values of $k!$ in memory (without modulus applied). Otherwise I'd have a solution for this.

Comment: Just to get an idea of the magnitude of the arguments. Something like $\binom{1.000.000}{1.000}\ (\ mod\ 37^4\ )$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n-k+1}{k} \binom{n}{k-1}$. To avoid issues with dividing by $k$, in case $k$ has an exponent of $p$, just keep track of the exponent of $p$ separately. For example have a cumulative tracker called `pow`. Now, if $p \mid n$, then replace $n$ with $n/p$ in the numerator, and increment `pow` by 1. Similarly, if $p \mid k$, then replace $k$ with $k/p$ in the denominator and decrement `pow` by 1. At the end, multiply what you have by $p^\text{pow}$. Some pseudocode:

```
function binommod(n, k, p, a): [Returns an array of nCi mod p^a for i ranging from 0 to k]
    answers = an array of k+1 integers.
    currentans = 1
    pow = 0
    answers[0] = 1
    for i in [1, k]:
        numer = n - i + 1
        denom = i
        while p | numer:
            numer = numer / p
            pow = pow + 1
        while p | denom:
            denom = denom / p
            pow = pow - 1
        currentans = currentans * numer / denom (mod p^a) [You should have an algorithm for this already, provided p does not divide k]
        answers[i] = currentans * p^pow (mod p^a)
    return answers
```

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, iterative identities like these are prone to coprimality issues when the denominator $k$ is not invertible mod $p^a$. I am not sure what you mean by tracking exponents separately.

Comment: That's why I said to keep track of the exponent of $p$ separately. I've elaborated on my answer.

Comment: Although I thought it was $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1}\frac{n-k+1}{k}$ ?

Comment: That's also a true identity, which could also yield a valid solution.

Comment: I have added pseudocode. Note that you can always divide by a number that is not a multiple of p (mod p^a). Hopefully you understand now.

Comment: This solution is O(k log(n + p^a)). With your bounds on n, k, p^a mentioned (10^8, 10^5, 10^8), this should easily run in under a second.

Comment: I have to compute the coefficients over many $k$ (so for example for $k=1$ to $10^5$, for some unchanging $n$), and so if max $k$ is $10^5$ then that's $O(k^2)$ runtime for $10^5$. I also tested it for speed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand what you were asking for. I've fixed the code to use your identity instead; it should still work in approximately O(k) time.

Comment: I tested it and it does not seem to work (although the error may be mine). For the line "currentans * numer / denom (mod p)" I tried "currentans * numer * denom^(p-2) mod p"

Comment: Oops. It should have said mod $p^a$. To find `1/denom` efficiently, try using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: So with the edit to p^a I now use inverse mod (extended gcd), answers still do not seem to match the correct results (I am comparing against a slow but correct n choose k mod p^e implementation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27002/discussion-between-mihir-singhal-and-user51819).